# Berry Boot "No Connection"

Tags: berryboot

Cannot get Raspberry 3B to load os list upon initial boot. Continuously receiving "Error downloading distribution list from Internet."

I've tried 3 different disk images including the berryboot version for raspberry pi 0,1,2,3 as well as the quad core 2,3 versions. Same error every time.

Also cannot get VNC to work or even ping my raspberry pi.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I received the "no connection" message when I did a reboot on berryboot. The solution for me was to click on the dropdown arrow on the "no connection" message, there you can specify your connection details (user, password) and then it reconnects and everything's OK.
Hope this helps someone